# compilation error :- packages are missing

Tags: java, maven, web-applications, servlets, maven-2

I am learning `maven` these days. During making Web application it shows error.

When I add servlets in the source location and add these changes in the `web.xml`. It shows `package missing errors`.

My imports in code are :-

1. import java.io.*;
2. import javax.servlet.*;
3. import javax.servlet.http.*;

When I write `mvn compile` in `command prompt` in `windows`. It shows errors.

Errors are as follows:-

1. package javax.servlet does not exists.
2. package javax.servlet.http doeas not exist.
3. Some errors related to above two.

Help me.Looking for your kind response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably just have to add the dependency to your web.xml.

check here maybe: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/servlet-api

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Also be aware that the javax.servlet dependency should almost always be scoped as provided since the application containers provide those classes for you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how have you created web application in first place. You can use Maven to create a sample webApp for you with jsut a simeple command. You can use lates Maven version (I used Maven 3.04) to use the below command

```
 mvn archetype:generate
```

then It lists out the templates offered and you are asked to choose one number.

Then chose 436, which is a Java EE webapp template for java version 5 (You can choose what ever version you like)

```
Choose a number or apply filter (format: [groupId:]artifactId, case sensitive contains): 247: 436
Choose org.codehaus.mojo.archetypes:webapp-jee5 version: 
1: 1.0
2: 1.0.1
3: 1.1
4: 1.2
5: 1.3
Choose a number: 5: 5
```

And then give the below required parameters

```
Define value for property 'groupId': : Priya.MyWebTutorial.org
Define value for property 'artifactId': : MyLearnersApp
Define value for property 'version':  1.0-SNAPSHOT: : 
Define value for property 'package':  Priya.MyWebTutorial.org: : 
Confirm properties configuration:
groupId: Priya.MyWebTutorial.org
artifactId: MyLearnersApp
version: 1.0-SNAPSHOT
package: Priya.MyWebTutorial.org
 Y: :
```

And you will have a webapp template created in the same folder, ready to use. You will have the dependencies already added in your generated pom.xml as below

```
 <dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.5</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.1</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

When you compile this web app, the servlet and jsp jars need for your application are automatically downloded into your local repository by Maven.

Comment: alternatively if you dont't want to start from scratch, just add the above dependencies in pom.xml and then clean install. You will get the jars needed.